How to use "Not In" with SearchOptions? - OData logical operators in Azure AI Search
I am using Azure.search.mocument.models.SearchOptions and I'm trying to set the filter to not(answer in ('X', 'Y')). So it looks like this:
SearchOptions searchOptions = new SearchOptions()
    .setFilter("not(answer in ('X', 'Y')");

What I've tried:

not answer in ('X', 'Y')
not(answer in ('X', 'Y')
answer nin ('X', 'Y')

Also, .setFilter("answer eq 'X') works just fine.
I get this error when doing the first two filters (not the "nin" one):
Invalid expression: Expression contains an unsupported OData language feature.

But in the Azure Search documentation, it says that "not" is supported: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-query-odata-logical-operators
Is there any way I can do a "not in" expression rather than doing an answer ne X and answer ne Y filter?

Can you try the following:
SearchOptions searchOptions = new SearchOptions()
    .setFilter("answer ne 'X' or answer ne 'Y');

This should filter out all the documents where the answer is not equal to X or Y.
You can read more about OData comparison operators here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-query-odata-comparison-operators.

This works but I'm wanting to use the "not" operator since it makes my code easier to parse through text and convert into OData. So is "not" actually unsupported in Azure Search?

NOT is supported but you would something similar again. I think your expression would be something like not (answer eq 'X').  in is definitely not supported. However do take a look at search.in and see if you can do something like not search.in(answer, 'X, Y'). HTH.
